# UIImage immutable but var

Tags: ios, swift, uiimage

The Apple documentation say:

> Because image objects are immutable, you cannot change their properties after creation.

But Swift happily lets me declare a `var image`. The only thing is that if I assign a new image to `image` it seems not to do anything. Is that correct? Am I just being confused here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a difference between immutable types and immutable variables:

This is an immutable type:

```
class Immutable {
   let a: Int

   init(a: Int) {
     self.a = a
   }
}
```

As you can see, the property `a` can be set only during initialization, therefore:

```
var immutable = Immutable(a: 10)
immutable.a = 10 // error, cannot change value of constant
```

However, we can change the value of the variable itself:

```
immutable = Immutable(a: 20)
```

which will now point to a different instance of the `Immutable` class.

If we have a mutable type:

```
 class Mutable {
   var a: Int

   init(a: Int) {
     self.a = a
   }
}
```

then:

```
let mutable = Mutable(a: 10)
mutable.a = 10
```

we can change the value even if the variable itself is a constant.

This distinction is more important for value types because the mutability of the variable becomes the mutability of the type.

```
struct MutableValueType {
   var a:
}

let immutable = MutableValueType(a: 10)
immutable.a = 20 // error

var mutable = MutableValueType(a: 10)
mutable.a = 20
```

Basically, any change to a value type is a new assignment to the variable itself, therefore it has to be mutable.

Comment: Yeah, thanks. I think I'm confused about something else.

Answer (score 1):

Image objects are immutable, but image pointer. `var image:UIImage?` declares an UIImage type pointer like `int *i;` in C language. You can change the pointer, let it pointed to another image object. That's what happens if you assign a new image to `image` variable.